# numpy.array Boolean mix with int

Tags: python, numpy

When I create the  `numpy.array` which has `bool` type mixed with `int`

```
np.array([True,True,100])
Out[656]: array([  1,   1, 100])

np.array([True,True,100]).dtype
Out[657]: dtype('int32')
```

It will convert whole array to type int, I ***guess*** maybe the int class is higher than bool which makes sense.

---

And, If I already have a `bool` type `array` as below :

```
#When I assign the value by using the index 
b=np.array([True,True,False])
b[2]
Out[659]: False
b[2]=100
b
Out[661]: array([ True,  True,  True])
```

It will treat the 100 to be `bool` `True`, this is make sense too.

---

However it confuses me when I consider both of the situations.

Could you please explain this a little bit?

Comment: @JamesLiu yep , there are lot of way can achieve this changes, I just wondering why.

Comment: If you don't specify dtype when you built the array, numpy will choose automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

import numpy as np

np.array([True,True,100])
Out[3]: array([  1,   1, 100])

np.array([True,True,100], dtype=bool)
Out[4]: array([ True,  True,  True])
```

you should used the `dtype` to desired data-type for the array.

Please check the document

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html

For you second question, please check the description at the `dtype` parameter,

**"If not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence. "**

you create the array with no `dtype` parameter, and the minimum for the value type for hold the sequence object is the `bool`, when you assign a `int` value it will be change to `bool`.

Comment: This is good explanation, still wondering why assign the value will change bace to bool type

Comment: The numpy array can only have a same type, the second array built with dtype bool so numpy will try to convert new data to bool type

Comment: @Wen please check the description at the `dtype` parameter, "If not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence. "

Comment: @saul ok fair enough