# Adding 2 Diffrent NumPy arrays with diffrent values inside (Boolean , int)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-science, addition

I am taking the Data Science course on DataCamp.On one of the examples there were some kind of lack of an explanation about the numpy addittion rules. I am sending the picture of the example and the question below. What i did not understood was how a 2 array with diffrent values can be add up and give a solution like that.

[DataCamp Numpy example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvwXl.png)

[Code Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHJlH.png)

```
In [1]:
np.array([True, 1, 2]) + np.array([3, 4, False])
Out[1]:
array([4, 5, 2])
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback I have added the input and output as a code line.

Comment: Thank you for editing the post. Your question appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757712 (the questions are phrased differently, but the fact that a mixed (bool and int) array gets converted to int is effectively what your question is asking.

Comment: When doing arithmetic, `True` has  value `1` and `False` the value `0`. So `3 + True` gives `4`, and `2 + False` gives `2`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers now i understand the stiuation.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a `numpy 1d array` as a `list` in python.

In fact you can see this if you case to a list like this:

```py
# cast to a list
a = np.array([True, 1, 2]).tolist()
b = np.array([3, 4, False]).tolist()

# print them out
print(a)  #  [1,1,2]
print(b)  #  [3,4,0]
```

returns this:

```
[1, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 0]
```

You are then just adding each element of the lists.
`a[0]+b[0]` , `a[1]+b[1]`, `a[2]+b[2]`

So the (numpy) result is this:

```
[4,5,2]
```

Because you are using numpy (which is a module in python) the plus (`+`) operation returns the result as a numpy list (which is the sum of both lists).

Note: numpy arrays are similar, but not identical to python lists.